# JS: not catching promise fail?

Tags: javascript

I am using video.js and using async/await for the `play()` function, which returns a promise.  I am not getting either log.  If a promise fails uses async/await, doesn't a try/catch "catch" it?
I threw a debugger in there and tested what `player.play()` was equal to and it was a pending Promise.

```
async function foo() {

    try {
      await player.play()
      console.log("testing")
    } catch(e) {
       console.log('error', e);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have the answer inside your question. The Promise is still pending for some reason. It is not resolved nor rejected

Comment: The interesting part of the code would be what's happening inside `player.play()`

Comment: There is a third possibility, which is that `player.play` never resolves or throws. Sounds like that's what's probably happening.